# How to create polygonal shapes right next to each other in CSS

Tags: html, css, css-shapes

I have created a polygon triangle and I want to stack them next to each other

I have used shape-outside however it does not seem to be working. 
I want this to be dynamic so more can be added without the need to change the code

```css
div:nth-child(odd) {
  width: 280px;
  height: 280px;
  background: #1e90ff;
  -webkit-clip-path: polygon(50% 0%, 0% 100%, 100% 100%);
  display: inline-block;
  background: url(https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/3/Harry-Potter-1-.jpg) center center;
  background-size: cover;
  float: left;
  clip-path: polygon(50% 0%, 0% 100%, 100% 100%);
  shape-outside: polygon(50% 0%, 0% 100%, 100% 100%);
}

div:nth-child(even) {
  width: 280px;
  height: 280px;
  background: #1e90ff;
  display: inline-block;
  background: url(https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/3/Harry-Potter-1-.jpg) center center;
  background-size: cover;
  float: left;
  -webkit-clip-path: polygon(50% 100%, 0 0, 100% 0);
  clip-path: polygon(50% 100%, 0 0, 100% 0);
  shape-outside: polygon(50% 100%, 0 0, 100% 0);
  left: -137px;
}


div {
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
```

Comment: Sorry to kick up a bit of a discussion. Why are you doing this? It doesn't seem overly practical. You cant put any content inside the divs because it is clipped, and at that point you might as well be using `<img>` tags which have other benefits (accessibility). Is this just a demonstration of principle? Don't get me wrong it is awesome.

Comment: Just to explore CSS and get to grips with it. It also looks quite cool.

Answer (score 2):

You could use the pseudo selector of

```
 :nth-child(even)
```

in order to select all 'even' elements.

I haven't used the clip-path (due to browser compatibility issues), so this wouldn't be the cleanest, but this (should) work on more browsers:

```css
.parent {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  margin: 2px;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin-left: -50px;
}
.parent:nth-child(odd) {
  top: -50px;
}
.parent:first-child {
  margin-left: 0;
}
.parent:nth-child(odd) .child {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  background: tomato;
  height: 70%;
  width: 70%;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  transform-origin: bottom left;
}
.parent:nth-child(even) .child {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background: tomato;
  height: 70%;
  width: 70%;
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
  transform-origin: top left;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child"></div>
</div>
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child"></div>
</div>
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child"></div>
</div>
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child"></div>
</div>
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child"></div>
</div>
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child"></div>
</div>
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child"></div>
</div>
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Simply adding `margin-right: -274px;` to `div:nth-child(even)` does the trick.

```css
div:nth-child(odd) {
  width: 280px;
  height: 280px;
  background: #1e90ff;
  -webkit-clip-path: polygon(50% 0%, 0% 100%, 100% 100%);
  display: inline-block;
  background: url(https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/3/Harry-Potter-1-.jpg) center center;
  background-size: cover;
  float: left;
  clip-path: polygon(50% 0%, 0% 100%, 100% 100%);
  shape-outside: polygon(50% 0%, 0% 100%, 100% 100%);
}

div:nth-child(even) {
  width: 280px;
  height: 280px;
  margin-right: -274px;
  background: #1e90ff;
  display: inline-block;
  background: url(https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/3/Harry-Potter-1-.jpg) center center;
  background-size: cover;
  float: left;
  -webkit-clip-path: polygon(50% 100%, 0 0, 100% 0);
  clip-path: polygon(50% 100%, 0 0, 100% 0);
  shape-outside: polygon(50% 100%, 0 0, 100% 0);
  left: -137px;
}


div {
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I have fixed your css quickly (so pardon mistakes) , now they are aligning next to each other and  you can add how many you want and they will alignt as long as there is space.

```
div:nth-child(odd) {
  width: 280px;
  height: 280px;
  background: #1e90ff;
  -webkit-clip-path: polygon(50% 0%, 0% 100%, 100% 100%);
  display: inline-block;
  background: url(https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/3/Harry-Potter-1-.jpg) center center;
  background-size: cover;
  /* float: left; */
  clip-path: polygon(50% 0%, 0% 100%, 100% 100%);
  shape-outside: polygon(50% 0%, 0% 100%, 100% 100%);
  margin-left: -141px;
}
```

and

```
div:nth-child(even) {
  width: 280px;
  height: 280px;
  background: #1e90ff;
  display: inline-block;
  background: url(https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/3/Harry-Potter-1-.jpg) center center;
  background-size: cover;
  /* float: left; */
  -webkit-clip-path: polygon(50% 100%, 0 0, 100% 0);
  clip-path: polygon(50% 100%, 0 0, 100% 0);
  shape-outside: polygon(50% 100%, 0 0, 100% 0);
  /* left: -137px; */
  margin-left: -141px;
}
```

and

```
body:nth-child(1){
margin-left:0; /* To clear the first marign */
}
```